# Typescript DeepPick partial properties as a way to handle default options

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-fest, defu

I want to pick all the optional properties of a nested object type.

Example:

```
// Options that the user passes. He must use 'a.b.mandatory'.
type Options = {
  a: {
    b: {
      mandatory: number;
      c?: {
        d?: string;
        e: string;
        f?: string;
      }
    }
  }
};

// The default options are for the non-mandatory parts of 'Options'. 
// If the user doesn't provide 'c' then I want to provide default options for it. 
// See that 'e' is mandatory like in Options because when providing 'c', 
// 'e' must be provided as well.
type DefaultOptions = BlackBox<Options>;

// -->
// {
//   a: {
//     b: {
//       c: {
//         d?: string;
//         e: string;
//         f?: string;
//       }
//     }
//   }
// };
```

Then, I can set my default options like so:

```
const defaultOptions: DefaultOptions = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: 'default value',
        e: 'mandatory-default value'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This is for later merge using a tool like [defu][1] to get the final options the user can safely work with:

```
function f(options: Options) {
  const optionsWithDefaults = defu(options, defaultOptions);
}
```

I want everything to be generically typed.

---

Edit: Added clarification with an example

```
type LambdaOptions = {
  aws: {
    lambda: {
      name: string;
      version: string;
    };
  };
  middy?: {
    middlewares?: MiddlewareObject[];
  };
  sentry: {
    dsn: string;
    tracesSampleRate?: number;
    rethrowAfterCapture?: boolean;
  };
};

const defaultOptions: DefaultOptions<LambdaOptions> = {
  sentry: {
    tracesSampleRate: 0.1
  }
};

const options: Options = {...};
const optionsWithDefaults = defu(options, defaultOptions);
// -->
// {
//   aws: {
//     lambda: {
//       name: string;
//       version: string;
//     };
//   };
//   middy?: {
//     middlewares?: MiddlewareObject[];
//   };
//   sentry: {
//     dsn: string;
//     tracesSampleRate: number;
//     rethrowAfterCapture?: number;
//   };
// };

// sentry.tracesSampleRate is protected by a default value


  [1]: https://github.com/unjs/defu
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the rule is to get the "non-mandatory parts" of a type. Why are `d` and `f` not required in `DefaultOptions`? Could you... describe the algorithm by which you make such decisions and we could then write a type function that works that way? Such deeply recursive types always have bizarre edge cases so I'm loath to even start working on it if I don't even understand the non-edge cases.

Comment: Like, *maaaybe* [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxElKW) is what you want, but without a [mre] with more use cases and a good description of your envisioned algorithm, it's impossible to know. Please [edit] to clarify the intended behavior of the type function.

Comment: The purpose is to allow the use to decide which of the properties to provide as default values. Some of them are mandatory and aren't. An example of this is configuration for Sentry: you don't have to provide it, but if you do you have to configure a DSN; a default value for % of traces samples, and non-mandatory property for rethrowing an error after capturing. The latter isn't mandatory and we can safely propagate it to Sentry's SDK default.

Comment: Sorry, but none of that really addresses my questions. If you can't actually describe the intended type transformation (e.g., "a property should appear in `Defaults<T>` if and only if...), could you provide a bunch of self-contained (not depending on third party libraries) examples of input/output pairs? Could you check [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxElKW) and see if it works for your needs or if it's missing something?

Comment: Ok, I made it work. It was a combination of your proposal and @Aderion's. [link](https://tsplay.dev/NV517w)

Comment: That looks mostly like my code. Shall I write up my answer explaining how it works?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that I removed the `-?` and just used `?`.

Comment: And therefore every property and subproperty is now optional, which isn't what your `BlackBox<Options>` is supposed to be, according to your own question. The `-?` is actually important to give you the output you said you wanted. Maybe `?` helps your use case but it has little to do with your question as asked. So I will write up my answer but I will keep the `-?` because without it, it doesn't give you what you asked for. Is that okay or have I somehow misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented something similar a while ago.

For a nice type to help with declaring your default config:

```
type Primitive = undefined | null | boolean | string | number;
// Deeply make all fields optional
type DeepOptional<T> =
  T extends Primitive | any[] ? T // If primitive or array then return type
  : {[P in keyof T]?: DeepOptional<T[P]>} // Make this key optional and recurse
```

Then you can define your default config with intellisense like:

```
const a: DeepOptional<Config>={...}
```

For the resulting type to be correct:

What you want to achieve can be done with a merge function returning a intersection of the types like.

```
function merge<A extends Object, B extends Object>(a:A,b:B): A & B
```

Since the result is A & B, B will overwrite A's optional statement if the same key is given without it.

You can check this out for a working example: https://github.com/Aderinom/typedconf/blob/master/src/config.builder.ts#L118

---

*Edit: Changed incorrect wording (union to intersection) based on jcalz comment*